# Disable live camera feed in ARSCNView?

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

Is there any way to disable the live camera feed and pass the custom video as input in ARSession?
I want to achieve [Record & Replay ARSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsession/recording_and_replaying_ar_session_data) by code.

Answer (score 2):

There you go :)

```
    var originalSource: if originalSource == nil || scene.background.contents as? UIColor != UIColor.black
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if originalSource == nil {
    originalSource = sceneView.scene.background.contents
    
    sceneView.scene.background.contents = UIColor.black
    
    } else {
    sceneView.scene.background.contents = originalSource
    
    }
    
    }
```

Comment: This seems to just make the background black

Comment: yea, turn the background black and redirect the data as input

Comment: But `var originalSource: if originalSource == nil || scene.background.contents as? UIColor != UIColor.black` doesn't even compile. And does your code really redirect the input? Looks like it simply shows a black background to the user and doesn't actually redirect it.

Comment: It will not work, the Black color will only change the color of the scene content and the camera will work simultaneously, I want to replace the camera feed with the recorded video.